# Balanced spanning tree (T) from undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

I have connected undirected graph.
I am looking for the way to construct the balanced spanning tree (T) of a graph

The specific about balanced spanning tree, I could define as follows:

1. If the root of the tree is r .All
   nodes could be divided to the
   levels.I.e all the nodes  which
   distance from the r (in T) is j are
   in the level Lj,etc.
2. For each node w one can define for a
   sub-tree T_w of T,such that w is its
   root.
3. The goal is to define spanning tree
   in such a way that for each level
   Li,for every two nodes u and v in
   level Li the number of nodes in the
   T_u and T_v is maximally equivalent.

Does anybody can advice  any algorithm/s for building such  “relatively” balanced spanning tree?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the edges are equally weighted? If not, how should differing weights be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about your expression "maximally equivalent."

This problem may not have a perfect solution, so the obvious thing is how much better can we do?

This problem in generality seems to be NP-Complete. Some greedy approaches might result in constant approx algorithms, if you are lucky.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be trivial.  Let G be your graph. It is connected, so there is an edge between each pair of vertices.  Using the definition, construct an arbitrary balanced spanning tree G' with the same number of vertices as G.  Starting at *r* in G' and an arbitrarily chosen vertex of G, map each vertex in G' to a vertex in G.  Delete all edges in G that don't have a corresponding edge in G'.

The resulting graph -- call it U for "updated G" -- by construction has the same number of vertices as G', and further by construction, an edge exists in U iff the corresponding edge exists in G'.  Thus U=G' and it follows that U is a balanced spanning tree.

Comment: The graph was said to be connected but not complete: for each pair of vertices there exists a path from one to the other, but the two are not necessary connected by an edge. Thus the suggested algorithm will not work: there might be edges in G' that do not have a corresponding edge in G.

Answer (score -3):

You want to construct your tree as an [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

You can find additional information and code used to implement it starting on [page 12 of this PDF document](http://www.heppenstall.ca/academics/doc/252/9_trees.pdf).

[This PowerPoint document](http://www.heppenstall.ca/academics/doc/242/c10.ppt) has some pretty pictures to help explain what's going on and also includes a Java implementation of the AVL Tree data type.

Comment: AVL Trees are not applicable to this problem. Even though an initial unbalanced tree may be constructed trivially, once the AVL Tree rebalancing process gets involved it will break the spanning tree property.

Comment: @Arjen Kruithof: The idea is to continuously readjust which node is considered the root node as you are converting the graph to a tree.  It will require some modification to the standard AVL tree since AVL trees are binary and spanning trees can have multiple (more than three) edges on each node.